# OracleLobCreator needs to work on [oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection], not on [class oracle.jdbc.drive r.T4CConnection]

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

I am getting below error while uploading the file contents to oracle 11.2 DB using spring/hibernate.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Error is:

```
OracleLobCreator needs to work on [oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection], not on [class oracle.jdbc.drive
r.T4CConnection] - specify a corresponding NativeJdbcExtractor
```

I am using oracle 11.2
Driver is ojdbc6.jar

Hibernate config

```
<property
    name="fileContent"
    type="org.springframework.orm.hibernate.support.ClobStringType"
    column="FILE_CONTENT" />
```

Stack-trace is as below

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not create Oracle LOB; nested exception org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: OracleLobCreator needs to work on [oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection], not on [class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection] - specify a corresponding NativeJdbcExtractor
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: OracleLobCreator needs to work on [oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection], not on [class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection] - specify a corresponding NativeJdbcExtractor
            at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler$OracleLobCreator.getOracleConnection(OracleLobHandler.java:360)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler$OracleLobCreator.createLob(OracleLobHandler.java:328)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler$OracleLobCreator.setClobAsString(OracleLobHandler.java:259)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate.support.ClobStringType.nullSafeSetInternal(ClobStringType.java:80)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate.support.AbstractLobType.nullSafeSet(AbstractLobType.java:159)
            at net.sf.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:118)
            at net.sf.hibernate.persister.EntityPersister.dehydrate(EntityPersister.java:387)
            at net.sf.hibernate.persister.EntityPersister.insert(EntityPersister.java:460)
            at net.sf.hibernate.persister.EntityPersister.insert(EntityPersister.java:436)
            at net.sf.hibernate.impl.ScheduledInsertion.execute(ScheduledInsertion.java:37)
```

Comment: what class do you have in this parameter ? <bean id="nativeJdbcExtractor"
class="xxxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: Hi, 
Its SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor class.


<bean id="lobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler">
        <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor">
                <ref bean="nativeJdbcExtractor" />
        </property>
</bean>
<bean id="nativeJdbcExtractor" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed after changing the type in hibernate xml file to "java.lang.String"

Before :
type="org.springframework.orm.hibernate.support.ClobStringType"

After :
type="java.lang.String"

Answer (score 0):

https://yiingw.wordpress.com/2016/02/25/invaliddataaccessapiusageexception-oraclelobcreator-needs-to-work-on-oracle-jdbc-oracleconnection-but-on/

> Solution
>
> No need to use OracleLobHandler, use DefaultLobHandler instead.

Have you seen this?

Comment: Hi Sayan,Thank you for the reply. I have done the change but still getting the same error. Just to add on , I am using EAP 7.0